# Why doesn't the noun 'code' take any article?

Tags: articles

The following quote from "The sorcery code" by DimaZales:

> Blaise was sitting in his study writing code.

lacks either the definite article or the indefinite article.

I wonder why? Is there anything I'm missing? Is the gerund that can take a direct object without the article?

Comment: Why do you think it needs an article? If you were *writing poetry* or *writing prose* there's no article. "Code" in this use, is the same as poetry.  It's a **type** or **style** of writing.

Comment: Thank you @Catija! However was hard to figure it out.

Comment: Judging from the title, I believe that this code Blaise was writing is similar to programmer's code. Programmers write code, not a code. (It's kind of similar to work, not a work, in most contexts.) To refer to a piece of code (in programming context), it's better to say *a piece of code*, imho. See also: http://nerdland.net/2010/06/code-mass-noun-versus-count-noun/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code, when it means computer programming, is a non-count noun, so it doesn't need an indefinite article.