# Articles with word 'parallel'

Tags: indefinite-article

While reading an [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(v=vs.110).aspx) I have noticed that whenever a word ***parallel*** is used, then there is no article '***a***' used:

> In the past, **parallelization** required low-level manipulation [...]. These features simplify **parallel** development [...] fine-grained, and scalable **parallel** code.

Why there is no article? I thought it should be:

- ***a parallelization***
- ***a parallel*** development
- ***a parallel*** code

Is it because words *parallelization* is abstract, *development* is uncountable and *code* is I don't know, uncountable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the word parallel itself, but (as you suspect) with the contexts in which it used.

> The *parallelization* sentence is not speaking of a specific instance of the process but of the process-in-general: every time you "parallelize" something it requires low-level manipulation.
>
> Again, what these features simplify is not one or more particular parallel developments but the process-in-general: every time you develop stuff in parallel it's simplified by these features.
>
> And *code*, likewise, isn't any particular program or app but code-in-general: every time you need code that's parallel, fine-grained and scalable, these features simplify the process of writing it.

Comment: how come I can drop an article when speaking about something "in general"? I didn't know that rule.

Comment: could you give some reference?

Comment: @MarcAndreson It's not so much a "rule" as a "rule of thumb", but that's the basic meaning of articles and similar pieces. They're called *determiners* because they *determine* which one or set you're talking about; but when you're talking about things-in-general they're "indeterminate"--they have no *term* or boundary, and don't take a determiner. It's pretty vague; but you might get a handle on it at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) on Determiner.

Comment: would I use an article if I want to add an adjective to something I talk about in general , e.g. *"everytime you need **a nice** code"* or *"everytime you need **nice** code"* ?

Comment: @MarcAndreson *Code* in the sense of computer code is almost always indeterminate; that *code* is a mass noun like *rice* or *money*. We never speak of ***a** code* in that sense: *code* is the stuff that an app or subroutine or function is made out of.

Comment: but if it's not "code", but something else talked about in general, do I need an article before an adjective?

Comment: An adjective does not inherently impose a requirement for an article.

Comment: So which answer is correct: (1) we drop an article because these are uncoutable nouns or (2) we drop an article because we are talking about things in general?. Or is it a combination of both?

Comment: And I really need to know this, because I am about to remove **all** articles from my research paper when I talk about something *in general* :(

Comment: "Uncountability" is not a property of particular nouns but of particular **uses** of particular nouns. It's the use that imposes uncountability or indeterminacy on a noun. ... There's really nothing but rules of thumb here; your best bet is to have a native speaker knowledgeable in your field proof your copy.

Comment: so: "completely indetermined = zero article", "mentioned for the first time = indefinite-article", "already mentioned or a specific thing = definite article", is this the rule?

Comment: Rule **of thumb**.

Comment: [This website](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/article.htm) says *"You **must** put an article in front of a singular count noun."*, so if I talk about a singular count noun, but in general, do I put an article? This website does mentions that I can skip an article when talking in general about mass noun :(

Answer (score 1):

That's not the word **parallel** that would imply the use of an article. In your examples it is used as an adjective:

> parallel development;
>
> parallel code.

So we should question why **development and code** take no article?

Answer:

> In this context they are used as non-count nouns.

As regards **parallelization** the same reason impliedly occurs.

Notice:

In some contexts, however, they can be pluralized when they have transferred senses.

Comment: is non-count the same as uncountable? why is code non-count?

Comment: Yes. When it refers to [computer programming](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55452/why-doesnt-the-noun-code-take-any-article).